# Sync rundeck grailsdb in two rundecks running in separate VM

Tags: virtual-machine, rundeck

I was trying the following:

Vm#1 with Rundeck#1 with grailsdb#1

Vm#2 with Rundeck#2 with grailsdb#2

Then I pointed the Rundeck#2 grailsdb#2 to grailsdb#1 of Rundeck#1

It was running fine but then I encountered "503 error" in the web gui.

When I change the db url in the Rundeck#2 to its local db path then it starts working again.

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!